verifier.verifyProof always returns false but snark verify returns OK
I am using a zero-knowledge proof (zk-SNARK) verification contract with Ethereum to build a voting system, and I’m encountering an issue where the verifyProof function from my contract always returns false even though I am able to verify the proof locally using snark verify.
Here is the code to call the contract:
const tx = await this.contract.verifyProof(
        [
          "2980467611110276362856309798789240499587853923856512415035388961914201796900",
          "179786624243634008147867657390779237509244028805551401467913173193257640164",
        ],
        [
          [
            "20856283976960340088911056794616498291197117521521173966825002738035354898883",
            "18624731802453431120867750535941376509672323857482113843995614427174072776684",
          ],
          [
            "17690013679362028198159825735490779586502180252495866187295237680436137889295",
            "20031478123355921130252938506204468519545263436742162219048821735836461108898",
          ],
        ],
        [
          "10408944023221719741536497030210005043734868725456146801080096017352583188601",
          "4923898169779068340657751318318929588597175288041151425367431723069226709606",
        ],
        [
          "4645182771559000340891993408880479299283914053096739455858934864478335847561",
          "5402194453111901699393941793302786609658420357108561051578482786150004217967",
        ]
      );

I have the contract deployed, I checked it by console logging the contract itself so that is not the issue. I also have the arguments plugged in as per the contract which I derived from the generated files proof.json and public.json. What could be the problem then?
